# IOS safari mobile iPad - reloads page instead of following link

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I have a link in a page which is well below the fold, (when the user scrolls the page it has a indication that the page reloads) and then clicks a link it doesn't follow that href, it rather refreshes the page.

Any ideas on what might cause this error?

Comment: It seems that safari (mobile) is the new IE(6)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a 3rd party service that hijacked all clicks only on touch screens in very rare scenarios.

Lesson learned, Always isolate the issue..